# Debug errors when submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this form requesting name:

```
<form method="POST" action="procesadordedatos.php" onsubmit="return validarFormulario()">

    <p>Nombre</p> 
    <input type="text"  id="campoNombre">

</form>
```

And this script checking data:

```
function validarFormulario() {

      var nombre = document.getElementById("campoNombre").value;


      if (numbre == null || nombre == "" || /^\s+$/.test(nombre) ||  nombre.match(/\d+/g) || nombre.length < 6 || /[0-9]/.test(nombre)) {

            return false;
      }

      else {
            return true;
      }

}
```

Script has an error: on the if statement, the first element to be validated says:

```
numbre == null
```

instead of

```
nombre == null
```

When form is submitted, firebug does not show any error as the webpage goes directly to the php file linked on the `action` attribute of the form.

How can this errors be debugged? Because they are not listed by Firebug until submitting, and when submitting page loads directly due to the invalid variable name.

Comment: This would be a great candidate for a unit test, don't you think? You may want to look into unit test tools for JavaScript to test such scenarios. This will help you flush out errors without relying on runtime exceptions to occur to debug - which, I might add, is a very bad practice for unit testing.

Comment: `numbre == null = true` but `numbre === null = false` because `numbre` is `undefined` and you'll have a falsy result

Comment: I try to said to you that changes to a strict comparison (`===`) instead of normal comparison (`==`) to avoid that. In your case `numbre` is undefined, not null, but with normal comparison it returns ambiguous result.

Comment: Comment your form `action` attribute for debugging, so that it does not navigate away to that .php file. Remember to uncomment it when you're done

Comment: Still I don't understand what you want to debug, you already know the error is in numbre instead of nombre.